# Data not inserted in table with entity framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, ado.net, console-application

I just created a local database in my c# console project, and also an ADO.NET connection with EntityFramework 6.2.0 to that database.

Now I try to insert my new data from object type `Kunde` into to the table `[dbo].[Kunde]` like this:

```
public void gastSpeichern(Kunde kunde)
{
    using (var context = new HotelzimmerverwaltungDBEntities())
    {
        context.Kunde.Add(kunde);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I create the object which i give to my method `gastSpeichern` like this:

```
Kunde k = new Kunde{Kunden_Nr = 1337, Name = "Dennis"};

dt.gastSpeichern(k);
```

But as you can see the table is always empty and the code runs trough without any errors:

[image]

this is my table definition: 
[image]

Comment: `context.SaveChanges();` returns an integer value denoting the number of records saved. Check the integer value after save operation.

Comment: The return value is 1

Comment: @SouvikGhosh any ideas?

Comment: You may want to check the coding guidelines for C#, especially capitalization, use of underscores and naming. Your code will clash in many aspects with what is expected of a .NET program. It will still compile, it will still run, it will just be a clear signal that you are not very experienced in .NET. It will also help you here, as discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/).

Comment: It will also save you a lot of pain finding out why the innocent German data point of "Alter" (Age) for a customer is a major pain with most databases.

Comment: sorry im not very experienced right - but this project is from school and they have this naming guidelines especially for database columns (with underscore), the variable names and method names are also given by my teacher.... but how does your comment help me with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your entity does not have a primary key. Add either a property "Id" or add an attribute [Key] to your "Kunden_Nr"

Comment: Kunden_Nr is my primary key?!

Answer (score 0):

It could be you are adding to your Object instead of adding to the list of objects:

```
 context.Kunde.Add(kunde);
```

instead of:

```
 context.Kunden.Add(kunde); (add to the list, in this case it's called Kunden)
```